# django social auth extra argument and white listed domain not working

Tags: python, django

for my django project I'm using google social authentication  which is working for me. now i want to allow particular email address which have my organizations domain only ( abc@example.com). hence only those mail allow to login who has suffix 'example.com'
somewhere i read that i need to write

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['example.com']
```

in my settings.py, but still i'm able to login by other-then example.com mails.
i also tried

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {'hd': 'example.com'}
```

```
settings.py
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxx....xxx'


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'localusers',
    'activity',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'thisproject.urls'


SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {'hd': 'example.com'}
#AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {'hd': 'example.com'}
#SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['example.com']

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'thisproject.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')



LOGIN_URL = '/account/login'
SITE_ID = 1

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

how can i fix this problem ?

django version-2.2.7

Comment: which package are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add and specify the authorized domains to your google API credentials.